# Lightning component - render VF page over account details on button click

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, iframe

I need to build out a custom lightning component which houses 1 button that will set the account details to an imbedded iframe. I have found a few [examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MPlLQAW) of components which render a vf iframe inside of the component but i am needing the iframe to be over the main details section of the record, not the lightning component.

This is needed to keep the button hidden when necessary without having to leverage custom buttons on different record types.

I am new to lightning components so i am mainly looking for an example or guide on how to do this.

Edit:
So we currently have about 4 different custom buttons on certain accounts. Each button calls to a vf page with an iFrame linked to another system which renders over the main details section of the record. We are needing to hide the button based on certain fields' criteria but do not want to leverage separate record types/layouts.

The VF pages are already created so i was hoping to just reuse them.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more as what is your use case? You may not need a VF page here. You can utilize the same component to render the details that you need.

Comment: i have edited my question to put a little more context. If you still need more i can edit as needed.

Comment: I am still trying to understand, so what do you want the Lightning Component to host? Dynamically show only 1 button out of 4 buttons? Or just show the dynamic contents within the iframe based on account attributes?

Comment: All i want the lightning component to do is host the button which will tell the page to switch to the iframe when a user clicks it. I only need this to work with 1 button and one page for now.